# MultiValue Parameter Not Working in SSRS 2017 for Oracle DataSource

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I am creating a `SSRS report` with oracle data source. I am passing multi-value parameter values as a filter to the Oracle `dataset`. Below is the sample query,

```
select *from FIN.FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION F
 where TO_DATE(F.CREATE_DATETIME) BETWEEN  to_date(:startdate,'YYYY-MM-DD') and  to_date(:enddate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
AND F.SUBTYPE IN (:subtype)
```

This query works when i pass a single value in :subtype parameter. When I passed multiple values I am getting no output. When Multiple values are in the parameter, its passed as a comma separated string. So i tried to split the string with below query. But getting Error in report processing.

> select *from FIN.FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION F  where
>   TO_DATE(F.CREATE_DATETIME) BETWEEN  to_date(:startdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
>   and  to_date(:enddate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND F.SUBTYPE IN (  select
>   regexp_substr(replace(:subtype,'''', '"'),'[^,]+', 1, level) as txt
>   from dual     connect BY regexp_substr(replace(:subtype,'''', '"'),
>   '[^,]+', 1, level)     is not null)

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your query is `REPLACE(:SUBTYPE, '''', '"')`. 
Why you are replacing a single quote with the double quote?

Values in the Oracle is always wrapped in single quotes like this -

```
F.SUBTYPE IN ('val1','val2','val3',.....)
```

So I think this is the only issue with your query.

For multiple input parameters which are comma-separated, You can use `Hierarchical query` as following (Repeating your query to provide you the actual query):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    FIN.FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION F
WHERE
    TO_DATE(F.CREATE_DATETIME) BETWEEN TO_DATE(:STARTDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
      AND TO_DATE(:ENDDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    -- changes after this line (IN clause)
    AND F.SUBTYPE IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(:SUBTYPE, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) VALUE
        FROM
            DUAL
        CONNECT BY
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(:SUBTYPE, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    );
```

This will support both single and multiple values(comma-separated).

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Tejesh I am now able to pass the multi value parameters with below clause in where condition INSTR(:subtype, SUBSTYPENAME) > 0   . I am trying to implement All if null condition also with below code,    WHERE        (INSTR(:subtype, SUBSTYPENAME) > 0  OR :subtype = 'ALL')  but always getting error. could you help?

Comment: Hi, I tried this method but i get an error of illegal variable name/number. But if I hard code the value for date parameter then it doesn't give me any error but after selecting multi value from the other parameter, the report data doesn't filtered out. any idea what's is happening